# How can I safely parse the month using PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime

Why does the following code return `12-2023`? It should be `11-2023`, right?

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-y', '11-23');
echo $datetime->format('m-Y');
```

This only happens when I run it on the 31st day of a month, like October 31st or December 31st. It seems that when we provide '11/23' as the date, and today is October 31st, PHP interprets it as November 1st. When today is December 31st, it interprets it as January 1st of the following year.

So `11-23` will be intepreted as `31-11-23`, and below code will return as `01-12-2023`:

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y', '31-11-23');
echo $datetime->format('d-m-Y');
```

I want to use this code to parse the month and year from a credit/debit card. How can I safely parse the month using PHP?

I also tried

```
echo date('m-Y',strtotime("10-23"));
```

But it returned `01-1970`.

Do I really need to prepend the input string with the date? For example, if the input is '11-23,' do I need to add '01-' in front of it to make it work with `DateTime::createFromFormat`?

Comment: If you want it to be in the month, you could prefix your date with "01-",  as the first of the month will most certainly be there. where as the 29th, 30th or 31st may be missing in some months

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just prepend a `!` or `|` to the format string

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('!m-y', '11-23');
```

Explanation in [the document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.createfromformat.php):

> If format does not contain the character ! then portions of the
> generated date/time which are not specified in format will be set to
> the current system time.
>
> If format contains the character !, then portions of the generated
> date/time not provided in format, as well as values to the left-hand
> side of the !, will be set to corresponding values from the Unix
> epoch.

Comment: For what it's worth, Unix Epoch is Thursday, 1st January 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.

Answer (score 0):

When you feed it with incomplete dates, PHP fills the gaps with *current* date/time. When that creates an invalid date, PHP helpfully "fixes" it for you.

At the time of writing, it's 31st October. But November only has 30 days, so it moves forward to next month.

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-y', '11-23');
$now = new DateTime();
var_dump($datetime, $now)
```

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2023-12-01 09:48:48.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "Europe/Amsterdam"
}
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2023-10-31 09:48:48.010803"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "Europe/Amsterdam"
}
```

To answer your question, yes, you have to specify a specific day of month (and even time) if you don't want it to be populated dinaymically (and potentially wrong).